# What are some elementary differential geometry textbooks that are self-contained and are intermediate level?

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, book-recommendation

What are some intermediate differential geometry textbooks that are more advanced than Pressley's, Barrett's, Christian's and Krezig's books, and are self-contained, but below the level of Spivak's vol 1, 2 and do Carmo's and Wolfgang's books? Can you also explain which topics I should pick up before I challenge myself to read more demanding ones and less self-contained advanced textbooks?

I already finished reading the elementary books I mentioned above, but still think I need a transitional book in order to continue to a more advanced one, even through the advanced ones I mentioned are still undergraduate level. These advanced ones are the ones that really cause me trouble.

Comment: Spivak isn't self-contained?

Comment: @RobinGoodfellow- it is too technical and abusive with these high level definition/terms and most of time these terms are explained in other book and therefore people need to read a intermediate one before reading it.

Comment: You realize differential geometry is abusive in general, right?

Comment: @Robin Goodfellow - No, only in terrible books

Comment: I always enjoy coming back to John Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds. Point-set topology and undergrad calculus are enough I think for it.

Comment: @Victor -- I'm not aware of any branch of mathematics that abuses notations, definitions, and classical terminologies more than differential geometry. I defend Spivak as an introduction because he points out these abuses and doesn't kid the reader into believing the general theory is easy. That said, Lee is also a delightful choice, though I'd recommend it to "pick up the pieces" after going through Spivak.